# php regex: find inline javascript in HTML document

Tags: php, regex

i need to find inline javascript with php regex. I can find external script, but not inline, can anybody help me?

Here is my pattern for external:

```
"/<script(.*?)src(.*?)>(.*?)<\/script\s*>/smi"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what about parsing the document with a DOM parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"/<script((?:(?!src=).)*?)>(.*?)<\/script>/smix"
```

(My first look-ahead regex ;))

Please note that you should not parse HTML with regexes, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/221213

Comment: Yes, this is for all scripts, but I need the one, without src attribute in opening tag

Comment: cool this almost is correct :) You just need to add ? after first * : "/<script((?:(?!src=).)*?)>(.*?)<\/script>/smix"

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all those cases where inline script can be used (i.e. all listener functions onClick, onBlur, onMouseDown, onMouseUp, on...)).

Comment: No, i haev HTML doc ant i need to find text like <script type="text/javascript"> var tmp = 3; </script> but not <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: @no, there are enough ways to run JS. Another way: `<iframe src="http://example.com/evil.htm"></iframe>`. A better solution would be whitelisting using an application like HTML Purifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/<script[^\>]*>(.?)<\/script>/si"
```

Comment: that's not good because it'll find only one character long scripts